# Unable to add an email address from another domain in GAE

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I want to send emails from another account in python mail API GAE. 
I found this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail

So I tried to authorize my gmail id from Google Developer Console > App Engine > Setting > Edit Application Setting

but this is showing

```
"Unable to add an email address from another domain"
```

**Edit**

I have project ProjectA deployed on abc@gmail.com
and I want to add emailId xyz@gmail.com

Comment: Same here... It worked until yesterday... I'll open a ticket.

Comment: Also, I noticed that previously added custom email address disappeared, as well as custom domains... The heck is going on?

Comment: @raz3r How you got this working earlier ?

Comment: Same way as you did, but now it returns this error...

Comment: @RohitBarnwal : this is what I am doing . but not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete steps that I have performed to add email xyz@gmail.com

1) Shared Project with xyz@gmail.com.

2) You will got an email to Accept Invitation .

3) Now open developer console with xyz@gmail.com

4) Now add the same email (xyz@gmail.com) under Application Setting. You can't add from abc@gmail.com.

5) Done.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently up until 7th January you need an administrator in order to handle email senders, custom domains and certificates. I tried with a super administrator and it worked. This has been confirmed by Google support in a ticket. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying this, and Google gives me an error "Server Error. There's a problem at our end." :(

Comment: Try logging out and logging in again. Or with an incognito window. As far as I can tell the new console is bugged as hell.

Comment: Just tried an incognito window and got the same error.

Comment: Yes, and just tried again and got the same error.  I used the link to give feedback to Google for whatever that is worth.

Comment: @raz3r . you got  any solution? because after sharing the project, there is same issue

Comment: Well my solution works because I have a Google Apps for business environment, it may not apply to normal Gmail accounts. Make sure both of you are owners of the application, I'd recommend opening a case on the Cloud Platform google group.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Google have changed something on custom domain. That is the reason they removed all email id from other domain as authorized email sender.

Now to authorize any email, you need to add that email here [2]

[2] https://console.developers.google.com/appengine/settings?project=your_project_name

Just make sure, your email sender is present in the list of Email API authorized senders. Now only thing is if you want to add abc@example.com as email sender then you must be logged in as owner using email john@example.com

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have admin access of the email domain, you want to add?

Comment: what do you mean by admin access ?

Comment: admin access of app engine project as well as admin access for custom domain if you are adding any such email.

Comment: Yes I have admin access of email where project is deployed. And I want to add other gmail id from where i can send emails

Comment: what email id you are trying to add, and is the email id that is used to logged in to see this page? Basically both domain has to be same.
For example if you want to add xyz@gmail.com then you need to be logged in with something@gmail.com to this project as admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100466/discussion-between-sunil-garg-and-rohit-barnwal).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add 'xyz@gmail.com' while logged in as 'abc@gmail.com'. Here are the rules for adding email addresses to the Email API Authorized Senders list from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail):

> All email addresses on the Email API Authorized Senders list need to be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts. There are restrictions on who can add whom to the Email API Authorized Senders list:
>
> - Application administrators can add themselves
> - Application administrators for applications hosted in a Google Apps domain can add noreply@domain.com, as long as noreply@domain.com is a
>     valid    account
> - Domain administrators of domains managed by Google Apps can    add any user in their domain

To add 'xyz@gmail.com', they needed to be added as an application administrator by 'abc@gmail.com' (which means accepting the invite), and then 'xyz@gmail.com' needs to log into the console for that applicaton to add themselves to the authorized senders list.

This is to prevent 'abc@gmail.com' from adding any arbitrary Gmail users to the Email API Authorized Senders list and potentially impersonating them.

Comment: still facing the same issue. I have shared with xyz@gmail.com and still facing the same issue.

Comment: In the case where this may be a prod issue with your project, I'd advise opening an issue on the issue tracker, and include full steps and screen shots for each step - https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list.